# What is the best method to paginate a C# list without using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, pagination

I need to paginate a C# `List<>` without using LINQ since I'm using .NET framework 3.0. What is the best way to do this?

What I need to do is read a list of files from a folder and display them in a gridview with pagination.

Comment: "Best" is subjective. Please be clear about your objectives.

Comment: Paginate a LIST - i.e. not from a database, all in memory?

Comment: yes not from a DB. in memory

Comment: If all data is in memory then what you mean by paginate? Gridview can handle the pagination as far as UI is concerned (by setting relevant properties such as page-size, page-index).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a GetRange operation, I suppose if this is a requirement. Try something like:

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
var items = foos.GetRange(0, 5);
```

So that'd get the first 5 elements, you'd obviously want to grab as many elements as you wanted. Starting from (count + element) next time around.